# Xcode7.3 swift project lost syntax coloring

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

My swift project has good syntax coloring on Xcode7.2, after I updated to Xcode7.3, syntax coloring has gone, except strings, numbers, and comments. And the shortcut keys "command+/" to comment is not working either. So is autocompletion. I created a new swift project, and it has the same problem. But Objective-c projects are working well.

I searched and tried deleting derived data, not working.

Another thing is throught Editor > Syntax Coloring, I cannot find Swift.

Comment: ok, i will try it and update the result whether it works or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved by reinstalling Xcode. It turns out the Swift syntax color file is missing. After reinstalling, it appeared in Editor>Syntax Color. Thanks @Darko